# Does a negative vector imply scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, axioms

Let's say I have a vector (or something that behaves like a vector) called $u$. Every vector in a vector space has corresponding negative vector $-u$. In this case does $-u = -1u$? I ask, because if we redefine scalar multiplication by some scalar $k$ such that $k(x, y, z) = (k^2x, k^2y, k^2z)$ then perhaps $-1u=u$ because $(-1)^2=1$. If this is the case then one of the axioms of vector spaces may have been violated, namely that there must exist some inverse of $u$ such that $u+(-u)=0$. Although I don't know if $-u=u$ implies that there exists no inverse of $u$ for which the prior condition is true just that this vector would not be denoted by $-u$.

Comment: One can use the axioms of a vector space to show that $-u = (-1)\cdot u$, where $-u$ is the inverse to $u$.

Comment: Defining scalar multiplication like that will violate some axioms, for example if $k \cdot u$ is defined to be $k^2 u$ (where say $u$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $k u$ denotes usual scaling) then $(k + l) \cdot u = (k + l)^2 u \neq k^2 u + l^2 u = k \cdot u + l \cdot u$.

Comment: It is even true for modules over a ring.

Comment: @Joppy I'm aware. I just wanted to know if it violated this axiom in particular